# How to create android library project in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-manifest

I want to develop library project in android using eclipse. I tried android developer website I can't get in. I need help for how can I change my manifest now my file look like this.now what are the changes I have to do ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Thinkpalm.gestureinput"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".gestureinput"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 9):

Select the `project` from the `Package Explorer` (eclipse) or create a new one and open `Properties` dialog by pressing Alt+Enter ( or right click + Properties) and check the `IsLibray` checkbox.

For more details read [Setting up a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html)